# DD_belatedPNG not working in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, dd-belatedpng

Might anyone know why DD_belatedPNG works wonders for my transparent pngs in IE6 and IE7, but not in IE8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the content attribute to specify multiple document compatibility modes. To specify multiple document modes, set the content attribute to identify the modes you want to use. Use a comma to separate each mode.

If a particular version of Internet Explorer supports more than one requested compatibility mode, it will use the highest available mode listed in the content attribute. You can use this fact to exclude specific compatibility modes, although this is not recommended. For example, the following header excludes IE7 mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=7;" >
```

This should force IE8 to run like IE7 and IE9 to stay as IE9

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog](http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2010/05/20/ie8_still_fa/), you have to use a [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx) meta tag for it to "work".

Comment: added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"> to the top of my page and works great! thanks.

Comment: That actually worked great, however it also forces IE9+ to emulate 7.  Should I just add additional?